# Nginx server doesn't redirect to index.html

Tags: reactjs, nginx

**Situation**

I have a Nginx web server with given domain name.
I have been granted with SSH credentials, which redirects me to `/home/my_name`. There I upload all the necessary files (react project) but when I refresh domain nothing happens.

**Problem**

As I looked out I should change `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file, but as it turns out I don't have permissions.
The `root` redirects to `/usr/share/nginx/html`

**What I have tried**

1. With `sudo nano` command tried to change `/etc/nginx/available-sites/default` root path. Nothing happened.
2. Entering `sudo su` unzipped project files into `/usr/share/nginx/html`. It worked, but in my react project I couldn't access $_POST. There was this error 405 Method Not Allowed.

I am desperate on this one, so please any tips would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was I didn't restart nginx server after saving `/etc/nginx/available-sites/default`
Restart command - `systemctl restart nginx`